# Toggle Class based on ID on hover with other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

so I have a table with a svg floor plan for a building and I would like to have it when the user hovers over one of the table rows the corresponding floor(polygon) in my svg diagram is highlighted via css with a toggling of the class. I am able to get the id's for each element. I am having trouble looping through the floor plan svg to toggle the class. Thanks in advance for any help.

the matching element for each corresponding element is an integer.

```
<table>
    <tr id="floor_1" class="js-floor_number">
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="floor_2" class="js-floor_number">
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
     <tr id="floor_3" class="js-floor_number">
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<svg>
    <polygon id="south_1" class="js-floor_inactive"></polygon>
</svg>
<svg>
    <polygon id="south_2" class="js-floor_inactive"></polygon>
</svg>
<svg>
    <polygon id="north_3" class="js-floor_inactive"></polygon>
</svg>
```

---

```
//vars
var table_row = $('.js-floor_number');
var figure_row = $('.js-floor_inactive');

table_row.mouseenter(function () {

    var row_id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var row_id = row_id[1];

    $('.js-floor_inactive').each(function () {
        var figure_id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        var figure_id = figure_id[1];


        console.log(figure_id);

        console.log(row_id);

    });

    if (row_id == figure_id) {
        figure_row.toggleClass('.js-floor_active .js-floor_inactive')
    }

});
```

Comment: Read the question for 10 mins. Can't understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ends with attribute selector **https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/**

```
var table_row = $('.js-floor_number');

table_row.mouseenter(function () {
    var row_id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var row_id = row_id[1];
    $('.js-floor_inactive[id$=_' + row_id +']').toggleClass('.js-floor_active .js-floor_inactive');
});
```

ID ends with _X will be replace

but I don't know your logic **.js-floor_active .js-floor_inactive** what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

without testing i'd say the lines

```
    if(row_id == figure_id) {
        figure_row.toggleClass('.js-floor_active .js-floor_inactive')
    }
```

needs to be in the each-loop and you need to change figure_row to `this`.
like this:

```
$('.js-floor_inactive').each(function() {
    var figure_id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var figure_id = figure_id[1];

    if(row_id == figure_id) {
        $(this).toggleClass('.js-floor_active .js-floor_inactive')
    }

});
```

rest of the code logic looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the IF statement inside the each loop, but that will only highlight the entered floor.

```
    var FLOOR_NUMBER_SELECTOR    = ".js-floor_number",
        ACTIVE_FLOOR_SELECTOR    = ".js-floor_active",
        INACTIVE_FLOOR_SELECTOR  = ".js-floor_inactive",
        allTableRows             = $(FLOOR_NUMBER_SELECTOR),
        allFigureRows            = $(INACTIVE_FLOOR_SELECTOR);

    allTableRows.mouseenter(onRowEnter);

    function onRowEnter()
    {
        toggleHighlightFloorByRow(this);
    }

    function toggleHighlightByRow(row)
    {
        var rowID = $(row).attr('id').split('_')[1];
        toggleHighlightFloor(rowID);
    }

    function toggleHighlightFloor(id)
    {
        getFloor(id).toggleClass(ACTIVE_FLOOR_SELECTOR + " " + INACTIVE_FLOOR_SELECTOR);
    }

    // Return as jQuery element.
    function getFloor(id)
    {
        var element;

        // Consider optimizing with "hashmap"
        $(INACTIVE_FLOOR_SELECTOR).each(function() {

            // Get ID of the figure.
            var floorID = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
            if (floorID == id)
            {
                element = this;
                break;
            }
        });

        return $(element);
    }
```

What you probably also want is to deactivate the one that leaves.
In that case you can add

```
allTableROws.mouseleave(onRowLeave);

function onRowLeave()
{
    toggleHighlightFloorByRow(this);
}
```